# How can I run automated tests that support real iOS devices, take screenshots, and identify controls by ID?

Tags: iphone, automation, screenshot

I need to run some automated UI checks on our native iPhone app. I'd like to be able to do the following:

- I'd like to automate a few actions and take screen shots.
- I don't want the tool to identify the buttons by image or text, as my app changes images and text all the time. I'd like to identify controls by ID.
- I'd like to run these tests on a real iPhone device.
- Lastly, when I complete one test, I need to access to settings to modify a few changes, then relaunch app to test. (no need to resume the app)

Is there a good way to achieve these kinds of automated UI tests?

Comment: What's wrong with the UI Automation instrument in Instruments? It's built in and can do all of the above.

Comment: @BradLarson: For shame, for shame, leaving this shopping question open like that.  Tut tut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the instrument that apple provides -  UIAutomation
It provides all expected automation facilities. Screenshots can also be taken. Check for documentation here [apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/_index.html)

Here is a nice tutorial to start with http://cocoamanifest.net/articles/2011/05/uiautomation-an-introduction.html

Comment: Hi AnrunGJ, Thank you for your response, I added another requirement for the automation tool that I'm looking for "•Lastly, when I complete one test, I need to access to settings to modify a few changes, then relaunch app to test.(no need to resume the app)" , I'm wondering if the UIAutomation has this function too? thanks & Regards